# why this code don't give me the same result ? situation with static and static {}

Tags: java, static

i have a problem in static with {} and static without {} what is the difference. i will understand if someone explain to me the difference between these two code: why the first code give me a compile-time error ? and how can i use static keyword with {}.

please check out my first code which has a compile-time error:

```
public class Lambdas {

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Calculate {
    int calc(int x, int y);

}

static {

    Calculate add = (a, b) -> a + b;
    Calculate difference = (a, b) -> Math.abs(a-b);
    Calculate divide = (a,b) -> b!=0 ? a/b : 0;
    Calculate multiply = (c, d) -> c * d ;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(add.calc(3,2)); // Cannot resole symbol 'add'
    System.out.println(difference.calc(5,10));  // Cannot resole symbol 'difference'
    System.out.println(divide.calc(5, 0));  // Cannot resole symbol 'divide'
    System.out.println(multiply.calc(3, 5));  // Cannot resole symbol 'multiply'

}


}
```

second code snippet works fine:

```
public class Lambdas {

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Calculate {
    int calc(int x, int y);

}


static Calculate add = (a, b) -> a + b;
static Calculate difference = (a, b) -> Math.abs(a - b);
static Calculate divide = (a, b) -> b != 0 ? a / b : 0;
static Calculate multiply = (c, d) -> c * d;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(add.calc(3, 2)); 
    System.out.println(difference.calc(5, 10)); 
    System.out.println(divide.calc(5, 0));  
    System.out.println(multiply.calc(3, 5));  
}


}
```

Comment: When you declare variables in the block they are only available inside that block.

Comment: yes, got it. but is there something i can do to make these variables out the this block scope ? and can you give me a scenario when i should use the static with {} ? please^^

Comment: Look up the difference between declaring a variable and instantiating a variable. You can declare them outside the block, instantiate them inside the block, then you can access them in other places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a static initialization block:

```
 static {

Calculate add = (a, b) -> a + b;
Calculate difference = (a, b) -> Math.abs(a-b);
Calculate divide = (a,b) -> b!=0 ? a/b : 0;
Calculate multiply = (c, d) -> c * d ;

 }
```

A class can have any number of static initialization blocks, and they can appear anywhere in the class body. The runtime system guarantees that static initialization blocks are called in the order that they appear in the source code.

There is an alternative to static blocks — you can write a private static method:

```
class Whatever {
public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();

private static varType initializeClassVariable() {

    // initialization code goes here
}
}
```

**your code is showing error, because  variable (like add,difference) has scope just only under this static{} block,and you cant access them on other methods,they are also like constructor ,so the code will also run when you instantiate the class**

Source [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)